# Dynamically show usage

Tags: dynamic, usage-messages

As the title states I would like to dynamically show `::usage` on several functions.

Let's consider two functions here:

```
funlist={Plot,Plot3D};
```

Thus I do:

```
Input[
  Panel[
   PopupMenu[Dynamic@whichfun, funlist], "usage should be here"], 
  Dynamic@whichfun]
```

Instead of `"usage should be here"` I obviously tried `(Dynamic@whichfun)::usage` but  it's complaining that the `Head` is not a `Symbol`, so I tried to convert it to a `Symbol` but it still fails.

Thus the question is:

How can I convert `Dynamic@whichfun` in order to be able to have its `usage`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the problem with evaluation, since `MessageName` is `HoldFirst`. You can use e.g.

```
Dynamic[MessageName @@ {whichfun, "usage"}]
```

or

```
Dynamic @ MessageName[Evaluate[whichfun], "usage"]
```

in place of `"usage should be here"`.

Comment: Thanks! It seems like I'll always do the same mistakes when I use Dynamic. Additional Question (might be to be edited): Do you know how to display the first line of the `usage` only?

Comment: @Öskå Not sure how robust this is, but I would use something like this: `Dynamic[First@
  StringSplit[MessageName[Evaluate[whichfun], "usage"], "\n"]]`.

Comment: It does the job, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `With` to inject expression:

```
funlist = {Plot, Plot3D};
Input[Panel[PopupMenu[Dynamic@whichfun, funlist], 
  Dynamic[With[{t = whichfun}, MessageName[t, "usage"]]]], 
  Dynamic@whichfun]
```

[image]