# Get brief help for a set of functions

Tags: list-manipulation

When we are in console mode or working with a notebook we can get brief help about a function just by shift-entering

`?function`

I would like to have a list like the following

```
{Map, Function, List, Transpose, Outer, Sequence, Apply, Tuples, \
Distribute, Thread, Equal, Fold, Slot, Reverse, Plus, Times, Total, \
MapThread, Inner, ReplaceAll, Rule, Composition, Through, Nest, \
ToExpression, ToString, Row, Part, Range, ComposeList, Compose, \
SlotSequence, Flatten, FoldList, NestList, Hold, Release}
```

and get a list of strings containing the corresponding help(s).

`?` cannot be mapped to a list of course so i am trying to find another way.

`?` works with Wildcards like `?*Plot*` so i suppose it accepts some kind of pattern matching.

Any ideas ?

Comment: `Information[#] & /@ {Map, Function}` isn't quite what you're looking for...

Comment: @cormullion this is nice but firstly `Information` corresponds to `??` and not `?` and secondly (and more important to me) in the notebook I work, I cannot convert the cells to a more usable form so to gather them as a list. I viewed the notebook with a text editor and I find it very difficult efficiently extracting the useful information.

Comment: strongly related [Dynamic usage message](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33294/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
#::usage & /@ {Map, Scan}
```

> ```
> {Map[f,expr] or f/@expr applies f to each element on the first level in expr. 
> Map[f,expr,levelspec] applies f to parts of expr specified by levelspec.,
> Scan[f,expr] evaluates f applied to each element of expr in turn. 
> Scan[f,expr,levelspec] applies f to parts of expr specified by levelspec. }
> ```

Comment: yes thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

You can map `?`. Just turn off its `LongForm` form -- like this:

```
Information[#, LongForm -> False] & /@ {Map, Function}
```

[image: info.png]

#### Update

The OP has asked why

```
cl::usage = "blabla"; cl := {1, 2, 3}^2;
Information[#, LongForm -> False]& /@ {cl}
```

> Information::ssym: {1,4,9} is not a symbol or a valid string pattern. >>

produces the error message shown. The message is pretty clear. `Information` has attribute `HoldAll` and wants a symbol or a string as its argument. But the message shows  `cl` got evaluated before `Information` saw it. Here are two ways to avoid this problem.

```
Information[#, LongForm -> False]& /@ {Unevaluated @ cl};
Information[cl, LongForm -> False]
```

both of which produce

[image: blabla.png]

as does

?cl

which is equivalent to `Information[cl, LongForm -> False]`.

Comment: Well spotted! Not mentioned in "Details and Options", but tucked away in "Options" anyway; it's always worth double-checking... :)

Comment: One quick question: When the function is defined with no arguments (like cl::usage="blabla";cl:={1,2,3}^2) then I get an error. Do you know a way to overcome this?